# Авторизация VK

Tags: авторизация, php, вконтакте

```
function curl($url, $post_fields) { // CURL
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera 10.00'); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
 return iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', curl_exec($ch));
}

echo curl('http://vk.com/login.php', 'm=1&email=login&pass=pass&expire=');
```

Всегда выдаёт, что неверный пароль, хотя он верный. В чём проблема?

Comment: Как насчёт API?

Comment: @stck, насколько я знаю, в API нельзя авторизовывать пользователя по логину и паролю.

Comment: На хабре есть похожие статьи: [Пишем модуль для авторизации в VK API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143972/).

Comment: @stck Можно.

Comment: @atnartur, не подскажете как? Или же ссылки на методы.

Comment: @atnartur, так дело в том, что они логинятся без окошек всяких. Есть база аккаунтов например, они все проходят авторизацию и накручивают тебе лайки. Не пойму вот, как они авторизовываются.

Comment: @fast, а как включить то? :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, пустота потому, что обычно тот пользователь входил, с другого IP / из другого гео региона. В таких случаях ВК дополнительно спрашивает последние 4 цифры мобильника. Ваш код не предусматривает обработку такой проверки.

Для накрутки лайков (*вопросы этики, кармы и лучей космической диареи оставим в стороне*) можно создать Standalone приложение, которым будет "пользоваться" ваша армия клонов. Для каждого аккаунта один раз придётся [получить access_token](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) - проще всего ручками скопировать его из адресной строки после завершения редиректа на `http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`. После этого сможете вызывать расширенные методы, напр. [`likes.add`](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=likes.add), из вашего приложения c любого IP, в т.ч. серверного, зарядив обойму полученных токенов.

Comment: @sergiks, да Вы прям гений! Это действительно то, что мне нужно! И там же я увидел метод friends.add. Протестировал на 1 аккаунте и всё работает! В очередной раз Вам огромное спасибо! Долго ждал ответа =]

Comment: Только ВК капчу еще может запросить, где-то на 10-ом вызове если бить их подряд, имейте это в виду

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на официальный раздел для разработчиков. Там есть описания методов для работы с API. [Документация ВКонтакте API](http://vk.com/developers.php#devstep2)

Comment: @atnartur, это я понял. Конкретные методы для авторизации по логину и паролю какие? Раз Вы знаете, что так можно.

Comment: Я знаю только, что так можно:) Больше я ничего не знаю про это:)))

Comment: Вообщем-то нашёл, но это совсем не то. Там нужно авторизовываться в приложение ещё. Лучше исправить бы мой код...

Comment: А через ваш код не получится. Контакт проверяет сервер, от которого пришел запрос. Если он не правильный, отклоняет.

Comment: А как например сейчас всякие программы для накрутки создают? Они ведь авторизовывают аккаунты, а потом например с них подписываются.

Comment: Это происходит через API скорее всего.

Comment: @atnartur, странно. Но там сначала нужно авторизацию через приложение пройти, чтобы открылось окошко и ты подтвердил..

Comment: В окошке что? Сайт вконтакте? Тогда это api.:)))))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function vk($host,$port,$date,$path){
$fp = @fsockopen($host,$port, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
return "$errstr ($errno) \n";
}else{
 $out = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n"
  ."Host: $host\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
  ."Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n"
  ."Connection: close\r\n"
  ."Referer: vk.com\r\n"
  ."\r\n"
  .$data;
fwrite($fp, $out);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$fp .= fgets($fp, 128);}
fclose($fp); 
return $fp;}}

// пример 
echo vk('vk.com',80,'POST','/login.php');
```

Comment: @fast, выдаёт пустоту.

Comment: а вы задали параметры отправки POST данных? а также нужно ещё не много по парсит ответ сервера =)

Comment: @fast, не догоняю, куда их прописать?

Comment: исправил код

Comment: @fast, получается так должно быть? echo vk('http://vk.com', 'ПОРТ какой-то', 'скорее всего пост данные', 'тоже что-то'); растолкуйте, что и куда, пожалуйста.

Comment: @fast, результат - Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (106028208)

Comment: http://webi.ru/webi_articles/6_7_f.html