# Авторизация ВК на сервере через PHP

Tags: php, парсер, вконтакте, авторизация

Встала задача во время написания бота для ВК. Как лучше всего авторизоваться ВК через PHP на сервере? Именно в самом ВК через логин-пароль, чтобы потом можно было парсить авторизованную страницу (нужно добраться до html-данных тех страниц, которые ВК не отображает для незалогиненных посетителей). 
Заранее благодарю за подсказки.

Comment: Ответь пожалуйста, какую именно информацию тебе нужно получить с страницы?
Если какую-то обычную, которая в открытом доступе (показывается всем, а не только друзьям), то будет один способ. Если что-то сложнее, то другой.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150993/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-vk?rq=1